# Does Cache.Insert with CacheItemRemoveCallback run when no user is on the page?

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I'm using cache insert to refresh cache on a page every 20 minutes, for example:
Cache.Insert("x", foo, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20) CacheItemUpdateCallback)

I'm wondering if even though there are no current users on the page, the cache will refresh every 20 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the callback will execute even if no user is currently making requests to your page. But there's one thing you should be aware of - the cache that you are using is an in-memory cache. And your ASP.NET application could be recycled by the web server if some conditions are met: high CPU usage, high memory consumption, ... If your application is recycled, the callback will not be called because all state saved in memory will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) isn't a page level reference. "One instance of this class is created per application domain, and it remains valid as long as the application domain remains active."